# How to visualize a taxonomy for web?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, visualization

I am trying to draw a taxonomy on a web page, where I can drill down the content of this taxonomy to get finally to links to other webpages.

The input is something like the following.

```
<root>
 <catSuper1 link="google.com">
  <subcat1-1>
   <item1-1-1 link="http://web.com/1" />
   <item1-1-2 link="http://web.com/2" />
   <item1-1-3 link="http://web.com/3" />
  </subcat1-1>
  <subcat1-2>
   <item1-2-1 link="http://web.com/1" />
   <item1-2-2 link="http://web.com/2" />
   <item1-2-3 link="http://web.com/3" />
  </subcat1-2>
 </catSuper1>
 <catSuper2>
  <subcat2-1>
   <item2-1-1 link="http://web.com/1" />
   <item2-1-2 link="http://web.com/2" />
   <item2-1-3 link="http://web.com/3" />
  </subcat2-1>
  <subcat2-2>
   <item2-2-1 link="http://web.com/1" />
   <item2-2-2 link="http://web.com/2" />
   <item2-2-3 link="http://web.com/3" />
  </subcat2-2>
 </catSuper2>
</root>
```

The taxonomy should be drawn as root and the sub elements directly under it. When clicking on any one for drilling, the old drawing will be cleared, and a new one where the clicked node is the root, and its children are drawn connected to it.

For each node, there should be an ability to click on a link to send us to another page, the same link specified in the attribute link.

I can easily change the input data schema into anything requested like json for example, but I have wrote the data as xml in the previous code snippets to represent my idea clearer.

Please advise,

**EDIT:**

I am new to data visualization field, so I am looking for an advise about what tool I can use to achieve my purpose, and how I can do so. I heard about d3.js, but after looking into it, I have no idea how to achieve what I want.

Best regards,

Comment: What specific issue are you having problems with because, as it stands, your question is too broad to be answered here. What have you tried already? What code have you attempted?

Comment: Taxonomy, what a field indeed. Will [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/) do?